# C++ Correct way to handle sqlite3_prepare and sqlite3_step errors

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a function I´m building using C++ and Sqlite3 where I will be issuing a simple SQL statement.

This function expects DML commands with no return (like: INSERT INTO, UPDATE or CREATE type statements).

I wish to know if I´m handling correct the possible errors on sqlite3 calls. This is the code I´m using:

```
void execStatement(sqlite* dbHandler, std::string sql)
{
        sqlite3_stmt* compiledStatement;

        int retStatus = sqlite3_prepare(dbHandler, sql.c_str(), -1, &compiledStatement, 0);

        if (retStatus != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement); // <-- Correct ?

            std::string errorMessage(sqlite3_errmsg(dbHandler));

            throw MyException(retStatus, errorMessage); // MyException accepts 2 params: int and std::string
        }

        retStatus = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);

        if (retStatus == SQLITE_ERROR || retStatus == SQLITE_BUSY) // <- Correct ?
        {
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement); <-- Correct ?
            std::string errorMessage(sqlite3_errmsg(dbHandler));
            throw MyException(retStatus, errorMessage);
        }

        return;
}
```

So, basically issuing finalize would be enough to keep things on track without affecting later calls to same database ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst I can't help with the use of `sqlite3_prepare`, `sqlite3_step` and `sqlite_finalize`, out of interest, why don't you just use `sqlite3_exec` (which wraps all those functions up): https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html?

`sqlite_exec` can be used like the following:

```
sqlite3* pDB;
if (sqlite3_open("Database", &pDB) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    // handle it
}

// Execute a command:
char* error = nullptr;
if (sqlite3_exec(pDB, "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Something='Hi'", _func, &object, &error) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    // Ruh-roh, there was an error:
    cout << error << endl;
    sqlite3_free(error);
}
```

`sqlite3_exec` will execute `_func` and pass `object` to each row it finds that matches the condition.

As a more concrete example, suppose we had the following table

> create_table Customers(id int, name string, surname string, postcode string)

We wish to find all customers within a postcode:

```
int getCustomers(void* pObject, int columns, char** columnValues, char** columnNames)
{
    if (columns != columns_in_desired_table)
    {
        // we expect this to be called on a specific table. if it's not called on a specific
        // table then the result is rubbish
        return 1;
    }

    // ensure we received the right object:
    if (std::vector<std::string>* name = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::string>*>(pObject))
        name->push_back(columnValues[1]);

    // indicate success with zero:
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    sqlite3* db;
    sqlite3_open(&db, "customers.db");
    // this will be assigned from our callback function
    std::vector<std::string> customers;
    char* error = nullptr;
    // getCustomerswill be called on EACH row in Customers 
    sqlite3_exec(db, "select * from Customers where postcode='1234'", &getCustomers, static_cast<void*>(&customers), error);
}
```

<sub>I've omitted any error handling here</sub>

Here, `getCustomers` is our callback function, and its signature matches [what is expected](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html)

```
int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**)
```

`getCustomers` will be called on each row in the table Customers that matches the SQL query:

```
select * from Customers where postcode='1234'
```

`customers` will get populated with all entries from our table. If no entries are found, the callback is not called and the `vector` will remain empty. If there is an error, `error` will be populated with the error message and a call to `sqlite3_free` will be needed to free the memory (we pass in `nullptr`, so sqlite3 handles the memory for it).

Comment: Tas, sql_exec will need a function call to check/receive data. This will make my code async and I will confuse my class design, where my function belongs to....

Comment: Alright I trust you know what you're doing then. As far as the documentation goes, you appear to be using it correctly; however, the documentation does warn against using `sqlite3_prepare`: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html

Comment: @Tas: How would you use the `&object` with one or multiple row as a result? Cloud you kindly add an example?

Comment: @BrunoBieri I've added a more concrete example which deals with a SQL query which may contain 0, 1 or multiple results.